# root_logger_handlers_backup = _root_logger.handlers.copy() AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'copy'

Tags: python

import coremltools

labels = 'flower-labels.txt'
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.caffe.convert(('oxford102.caffemodel', 'deploy.prototxt'), image_input_names='data', class_labels='class_labels.txt')

coreml_model.save('FlowerClassifier.mlmodel')

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. Please revise to explain better what you're trying to accomplish and how it's failing.

Comment: @ isherwood can you help i need to update the values in my form look my code snippet as i am refreshing my page but still it is showing the same button name submit which i have wriiten before in my values now i want to update it with the name login .

Comment: Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn what's expected of you when you post a question.

Comment: please help with this question?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to format your code properly (use the editor), and you need to explain the problem. Don't beg for help in comments.

Comment: Also, there's an answer below to which you have not responded.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that  `values` is not a valid attribute for a [button element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input). You need to use `value`.

```html
<form action= "homepage.html">
    user name :<input type="text" name="user_name" required="required">
    <br>
    user password :<input type="text" name="user_password" required="required">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="login">
</form>
```